# re2 does not seem to give correct results for some patterns when compared to pcre

Tags: regex, pcre, re2

I was trying to use both pcre and re2 and I came up with the following observation.

When I give the string as

> "ab cd"

and the pattern as

> "^[^c]"

re2 returns NO MATCH but its actually a match.

That is to say when I type this `RE2::FullMatch("ab cd", RE2("^[^c]"))` I get FAIL/No Match.

Please let me know if I am going wrong somewhere or what is the problem?

Comment: I suspect `FullMatch` means the engine tries to match the _whole_ regex with the _whole_ string, and discards any partial match.

Comment: @Jerry It is a match right? The **whole** string does match with the **whole** pattern. Atleast for all other regex's its true isn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't match the whole string. To match the whole string, you might have to use something like ^[^c]+c[^c]+$. And I know only one regex that it's true (i.e. matches only if whole pattern matches whole string): Java's .matches method and Python's `.match`. There may be more, but not in C#, Javascript, Perl, PHP AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RE2::FullMatch matches the entire string, like Jerry says.

> There are two basic operators: RE2::FullMatch requires the regexp to
>   match the entire input text, and RE2::PartialMatch looks for a match
>   for a substring of the input text, returning the leftmost-longest
>   match in POSIX mode and the same match that Perl would have chosen in
>   Perl mode.

https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/CplusplusAPI